# ¿Cómo utilizo una ecuación en integrate.odeint que haya sido recibida por una entrada de texto?

Tags: python, scipy

Si escribo yo la ecuación en la función como en el ejemplo1, odeint funciona normal pero si trato de recibir la ecuación desde un input, me sale el siguiente error: **ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-2*x**3+12*x**2-20*x+8.5'**
Mi objetivo es hacer una interfaz gráfica para resolver ecuaciones diferenciales

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import integrate


def f(y,x):        
    return -2*x**3+12*x**2-20*x+8.5



def g(y,x):
            
    ec=input("Escribe la funcion")
    return ec

y0=1
x=np.linspace(0,4,9)

ejemplo1=integrate.odeint(f,y0,x)
ejemplo2=integrate.odeint(g,y0,x)

fig, axes=plt.subplots()
axes.plot(x,ejemplo1,'o')
axes.plot(x,ejemplo2)
plt.show()
```